# Unable to connect rabbitmq from another server using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

when I have my spring boot applications and rabbitmq on same server, spring boot application is able to connect to rabbitmq.

**properties in yml file:**

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: 127.0.0.1 
    port: 5672 
    username: guest 
    password: guest
```

But when I separated the rabbitmq and spring boot apps to different servers, spring boot app is unable to connect to rabbitmq.

**properties in yml file:**

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: **.**.** (IP-ADDRESS)
    port: 5672
    username: dev_user
    password: Dev@123
```

**Error in spring boot application:**

```
[INFO ] 2020-03-24 16:06:29.915 [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#0-74] SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Restarting Consumer@322defb4: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
[INFO ] 2020-03-24 16:06:29.916 [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#0-75] CachingConnectionFactory - Attempting to connect to: [**.**.**.**:5672]
[ERROR] 2020-03-24 13:33:11.820 [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#0-1] SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

Any configuration changes required in rabbitmq or spring boot app ?

Answer (score 0):

Who hosts your two servers? Are there firewalls set-up between the two? Then you need to enable the RabbitMQ ports.

It simply sounds like your RabbitMQ server is not (network) reachable from your Spring Boot host.

Comment: its formatting issue, please check the question now. i have updated

Comment: 15672 port already opened and I am able to access rabbitmq server from web.

Comment: note that 15672 is your http web interface. rabbitmq sends amqp messages on port 5761/2 and it could very well be that this type of traffic is blocked. so you cannot just check it from your own machine.

Comment: so what are the ports in rabbitmq server should be opened ? also I have added few more log messages. please check

Comment: The one you specified in your properties file, which is 5672. Note, it is _not_ 15672.

Comment: you mentioned: port 5761/2 , is it 5761 and 5762 ?

Comment: Yup, for without and with TLS. See here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html